# Bash script and curl: how to get status code and content and store in var in same command

Tags: bash, redirect, curl, stdout, file-descriptor

In PHP or Python, for example, you cand do curl and receive a object with all properties organized.

In bash I have to invoke curl application.

I need to get status code and content in same command (its obvious because the status code is relationed with success or not to get content). But how I can do this?

I am trying this:

```
# get url in function
urlcurl=$(echo $@)
# create new file descriptor and redirect to STDOUT
exec 3>&1
# get curl status code and store in curlstatuscode
curlstatuscode=$(curl -L -k -w "%{http_code}" -o >(cat >&3) --silent \"${urlcurl}\")
```

My problem is about content: When I execute this in terminal I receive content in STDOUT (that is the command had to do). But I am trying to store this STDOUT using regular redirect expressions and they not work.

One example:

```
exec 3>&1
HTTP_STATUS=$(curl -k --silent -L -w "%{http_code}" -o >(cat >&3) 'http://example.com')
echo $HTTP_STATUS
```

If you not understood what I am trying to do, roughly mode (and invalid) would be something like that:
***(I know that is invalid, I only want to clarify)***

```
HTTP_CONTENT=$(echo `HTTP_STATUS=$(curl -k --silent -L -w "%{http_code}" -o >(cat >&3) 'http://example.com'`)
```

HTTP_CONTENT will get get content and HTTP_STATUS will get curl status code.

Please do not say to user another language. I need to solve this in bash. Is very simple to do that in other languages (mainly oriented objects). I really want to do this in bash.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since http status is the last line in curl output, you can do like this in BASH:

```
out=$(curl -k --silent -L -w "\n%{http_code}" 'minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=apterixbr')
http_status="${out##*$'\n'}"
http_content="${out%$'\n'*}"
```

Comment: worked in part. if I get no content (like when you get timedout), http_status and http_content will be empty. http_content is OK to be empty, but http_status had to be timedout code.

Comment: One way is use -o option after 'http://example.com' to write in file, but I do not want provoke write in storage without really need this.

Comment: other test failed: sometimes status code will not be in last line.

example:


curl -k --silent -L -w '%{http_code}' 'https://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=apterixbr'

Comment: Check updated answer. `"\n%{http_code}"` will ensure one newline before status code.

Comment: now worked as a charm. thank you! hope the best for you :)